# mysql statement not to include an underscore in results

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql statement like this

```
$sql_insertwotd = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE word != '' AND word NOT LIKE '%\_%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

for some reason it it will still pull up a word with an underscore. I read this is the proper format to clarify an underscore with a .

I dont want it to select a word that contains an underscore

Comment: Looks like it should work already

Comment: it doesnt, for some reason it will still pull up underscores

Comment: Your code is ok. It should work.

Comment: Post your schema if possible. And post your data you are using

Comment: Can you add some sample data to a fiddle where it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `TWO BACKSLASHES` (`\\`) and it should work

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE word != '' AND word NOT LIKE '%\\_%' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Aren't these Backslashes? and not `FORWARD SLASHES` :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need an explicit escape:

```
word NOT LIKE '%/_%' ESCAPE '/'
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

By default \ is the escape character and your query should work as is.